# how to convert pointer from class function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, type-conversion

I am using visual studio 2012 professional
I have class log:

```
class log
{
   //some code
   private:
       int check();
};
```

and in another class i have pointer to function like this in constructor:

```
class fun

{
     //some code
public:
    fun(int (*wsk)());
}
```

and when I try to send check function from class log to constructor fun I get error:

```
typedef int (*fwsk)();
fwsk gwsk = check;
fwsk gwsk = (void *)check;
```

How to make it working?

Comment: error C3867: 'log::check': function call missing argument list; use '&log::check' to create a pointer to member

Comment: Can you give us a minimal code example that when compiled gives us the same error please.

Comment: Well did you do what the error told you to do and use &log::check?  That would be my first step.  check by itself has no scope so how is the compiler supposed to know what it is?  I don't know if that will work on a non-static function but that is what I would try first.

Comment: yes i tried fwsk gwsk = &log::check; then i got this error: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int (__thiscall log::* )(void)' to 'fwsk'

Comment: We don't have enough code to ascertain the problem. You need to give us more of your code. Put it in the question as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Member functions take an invisible first argument `this`

so `int log::check` is a function pointer of type:

```
typedef int (log::*function_pointer_type)(void);
```

Unfortunately, this will never be the same type as

```
typedef int (*fwsk)(void);
```

You could use `std::bind` in C++11 to get around this and pass in a generic function.

Example:

```
typedef std::function<void(int)> fwsk;

class Log
{
public:
   int check(){}
};

class fun
{
   //some code
   public:
      fun(const fwsk& wsk){}
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Log l;

  fun f(std::bind(&Log::check,&l));
}
```

Comment: can u write an example?